# Why does emacs sometimes insert weird characters at the top of my file?

Tags: linux, string, unix, emacs, random

Every so often, when I save a file using emacs I open the file to find a weird string of characters inserted at the beginning of the file. I have noticed this on multiple computers, so I don't believe it is specific to my machine.

I'm running Ubuntu 9.04 with GNU Emacs version 23.1.1.

Here is a sample of what I found today while editing a latex document:

```
B1;2305;0c\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Am I perhaps closing the file incorrectly?

Comment: If you want your text editor to *always* insert weird characters, use Vi(m) :)

Answer (score 6):

Are you running Emacs in the shell or under X? That looks like a terminal problem (similar to the escape sequences you see if your terminal doesn't like your cursor keys et al.)

Comment: I'm running emacs in the shell; I'm using bash version 4.1.5(1).

Comment: In the shell, can you please run "head -2 test.tex | od -t c" on one of the corrupted files and post the results? Maybe that will shed light.

Comment: no luck. that command just spits out the text as I have it. I should mention that the characters always look similar; i.e. they start with B and have three semicolons. I haven't paid enough attention to see if it is always the SAME characters.

Comment: OK, that's actually good, because it shows your file on disk doesn't get corrupted.

Comment: I guess you're seeing ANSI escape sequences that Emacs tries to clear the screen with. (23 cursor down or something along those lines.) Do you get more funny codes when you enter Esc x redraw-display?

Comment: OK, I'd guess your TERM environment variable needs to be set to something different, but that's where I have to resort to google, too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's unicode byte order mark?  What does <kbd>C-h v</kbd>`buffer-file-coding-system` say?  If it's something that ends with "with-signature" (e.g., `utf-8-with-signature`), then set it to the none "with-signature" version (<kbd>M-x</kbd>`set-buffer-file-coding-system` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `utf-8`).